# Create a loop to change ints in a list to another int?

Tags: python

How do I take a list of numbers

```
numList = []

while len(numList) <= 1000:
    numList.append(1)

while len(numList) <= 1000:
    numList.append(0)

print(numList)
```

Now how would I go about changing those to 0?

A for loop?

Comment: Do you simply want a list that has 1,000 elements of value `0`? Try `numList = [0] * 1000`

Comment: Your second *while* loop will never run because `len(numList) == 1000` after the first loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not changing the first set of elements you add.  See the comment I added to your code:

```
numList = []

while len(numList) <= 1000:
    numList.append(1)

# the numList is already a thousand elements long, so the while loop
# body is NEVER executed.
while len(numList) <= 1000:
    numList.append(0)
```

---

Try this instead:

```
numList = []

while len(numList) <= 1000:
    numList.append(1)

for i in range(0, 1000):
    numList[i] = 0

print(numList)
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. The for loop works. I wasn't sure how to execute. Thank you very much. I just used len(numList) instead of 1000. Thanks again.

Comment: "*I just used len(numList) instead of 1000*" - that's even better.  Good work.

Answer (score 0):

Change what you are appending to it:

```
while len(numList) <= 1000:
  numList.append(0)
```

Unless you are changing the existing array of [1, 1, 1, ...] to [0, 0, 0, ...] in which case you can use a list comprehension:

```
numList = [0 for x in range(len(numList))]
```

Comment: It still prints [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]... Thats why I am stuck

Comment: You're not running it correct then.  If there are no occurrences of 1, it should not have a 1.

Comment: @Casey, please show us the code that "still prints [1, 1, ..."

Comment: I don't understand how I could be running this incorrectly. I need to make a list with 1000 "1". I then need to make all of those "1" "0"s.

Comment: Read the second part of my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it, more clear;

```
numList = [1,2,3,4,5]
t = lambda x: [0 for x in numList]
print (t(numList))
```

Result;

```
>>> 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>>
```